# Textbox which should have both Autocomplete and able to type our text

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a `textbox` which should have `autocomplete` where I will be binding name as value and id as `email-id`. And I want to type any `email-id` in this textbox.

> Direct Question: I want the same as "To" address textbox which is in gmail or microsoft account.

This textbox is used to fill email address before sending. I have a list which will bind the names and email-id, but if i want another email-id to type it is not possible.

Comment: did you tried anything ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Autocomplete`](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) object from [JQuery UI Official Website](https://jqueryui.com/) to perform this task :

```js
$(function() {
  var toAdresses = [ // Should be populated thanks to AJAX call to database of To-adresses
    "Amelia@gmail.com",
    "Franck@webhost.com",
    "Kaithleen@provider.net",
    "Victor@hydra.cs",
  ];
  
  // Setting autocomplete functionality
  $("#input_text_to").autocomplete({
    source: toAdresses
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="To..." id="input_text_to" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selectize.js at http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ - check the Email Contacts example.